Why can't I access headers from an HttpResponse?
I’ve made a simple rest api & website with a logjn/register system in kotlin that mostly works, but I’m having a problem with one thing. After successful registration I want to return an access token and a refresh token to the client through headers and it seems that the client gets these in the headers as I can see them in the browser console, but I can’t access them in code, as there seems to be no headers? That’s a bit weird and I don’t know what to do with it.
Here's how the Network tab in the website inspector looks like
As you can see here, the headers are there in the Network tab of the browser inspector, but in the console they’re not being printed.
Here’s the client code:
button {
        +"Register"
        onClick = {
            if (!awaitingResponse) {
                scope.launch {
                    awaitingResponse = true
                    val result: HttpResponse = register(providedUsername, providedPassword)

                    // Log all headers first to see what's available
                    result.headers.forEach { name, value ->
                        console.log("Header: $name = $value")
                    }

                    console.log(result.headers)

                    val authToken = result.headers["auth-token"]
                    val refreshToken = result.headers["refresh-token"]

                    console.log("Auth-Token: $authToken")
                    console.log("Refresh-Token: $refreshToken")

                    if (authToken != null && refreshToken != null) {
                        saveTokens(authToken, refreshToken)
                    }

                    awaitingResponse = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

val jsonClient = HttpClient {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
}

suspend fun register(username: String, password: String): HttpResponse {
    return jsonClient.post("http://localhost:8080/api/user/register") {
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        setBody(UserRequest(username, password))
    }
}

and here’s the server code:

post("/register") {

        val userRequest = call.receive<UserRequest>()

        val createdUser = userService.save(user = userRequest.toModel()) ?: return@post call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)

        call.response.header(name = "id", value = createdUser.id.toString())

        call.response.header(name = "auth-token", value = jwtService.createAccessToken(createdUser.username))
        call.response.header(name = "refresh-token", value = jwtService.createRefreshToken(createdUser.username))

        logger.info(call.response.headers["auth-token"])
        logger.info(call.response.headers["refresh-token"])

        call.respond(message = HttpStatusCode.Created)

    }

Even when using a javascript command to print the same thing, there are no headers.
Here's how the Console looks like in the website inspector
